# getElementByClassName isn't work

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have a problem why I do not want to work it tired for some time. I just started learning js. Thanks great for the help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="test" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png">
        <img class="test" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png">

        <script>
            var test = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
            test.onclick = function () {
                alert("test");
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: I can't see your jQuery script inserted anywhere, also what is located in that `script.js` file?

Comment: @ZombieChowder the code in the example is vanilla javascript, jQuery isn't required.

Comment: @JohnC huh yeah, I guess it flew right pass me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the eventlistener to every element. So you need to loop through the elements because `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements. You can do it like this:

```js
function trigger() {
  alert("test");
}

var test = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

for (var i = 0, j = test.length; i < j; i++) {
  test[i].addEventListener("click", trigger);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <img class="test" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png">
  <img class="test" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png">

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a javascript developer, but I Think it should be

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];
test.onclick = function (){
    alert("test");
};
```

as `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test");
```

returns an array.
You have to loop through that array and apply the onclick to each element.

Comment: It returns an array-like live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an array :)

Comment: OK, sorry but at least you can loop through it :)

Comment: In most browsers, it actually returns a NodeList Object which is similar to HTMLCollection object.

Comment: @asmmahmud No it doesn't. The "new" `.querySelector*` methods return [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)s

Comment: @Andreas According to  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp W3School , it returns a NodeList Object. But, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName > Mozilla Developer Network,  it returns a HTMlCollection. Which one is correct?

Comment: @asmmahmud The [specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-getelementsbyclassname) which states: _"The `getElementsByClassName(classNames)` method, when invoked, must return the [list of elements with class names classNames](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-getelementsbyclassname) for context object."_ with (from the link) _"The list of elements with qualified name qualifiedName for a node root is the **HTMLCollection** returned by the following algorithm..."_; Hence the MDN is correct and w3schools is not...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answers, the method `document.getElementsByClassName`  return a NodeList Object which is Array like object with numeric indices (0, 1...) and you can loop through it using `for .. in` loop or `Array.prototype.forEach.call` method and can attach the event listener to every node.

```
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var node;
for (node in tests) {
  node.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        // do something
   });
}
```

Or in the following way:

```
    var tests = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(tests, function(node){
      node.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            // do something
      });
   });
```

Main point is you have to add event listener to every element.